# Are seda and the actor model essentially equivalent?

Tags: concurrency, erlang, actor, message-passing

SEDA is essentially a set of independent "services" that communicate with each other via queues, which could further be abstracted as message passing.

The actor model is a set of independent functions, which communicate with each other through message passing.

Aren't they essentially equivalent? Am I missing some key difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/proj/seda/ (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160811044810/http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/proj/seda/)), they don't seem to be. SEDA could easily be implemented over actor model, but an actor-based application doesn't need to have anything like SEDA's stages.